# Rank each link on click

Tags: jquery

My function counts how many anchors on a page and returns its count on click. However, I need to include this function in a click function initially

```
$("a").each(function(count) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        $(this).data('link'+count); 
            alert('link'+count);
            return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/43tmut7t/15/

Like this:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    if () { 
//do stuff
    } else { 
//otherwise do this
    }
});
```

Comment: I think both of the fiddles are the same

Comment: Do you want the click to alert the number of times each anchor was clicked, or the index of the anchor?

Comment: Explain exactly what expectations are. Are you wanting individual link counts? You are starting with indexes so it is already confusing

Comment: @j08691 I believe OP wants the index of the anchors as that's what the first set of code is returning

Comment: @Huangism - yeah I wasn't sure. I started off answering the # of clicks and then added an answer for the index.

Comment: Yes, individual link counts. All links on a page. Not within any particular structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after

http://jsfiddle.net/43tmut7t/16/

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var count = $(this).index('a');
    alert('link' + count);
    return false;
});
```

This way, it will return the index based on all the anchors on the page regardless of structure

Comment: wouldn't be any need to store the data if it's only needing an index. Also not storing properly using `data()`

Comment: Yea I thought I leave it in because OP had it i the question, nvm the data storage was wrong to start with

Comment: However, if the links are not in an LI then the links aren't not ranked anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/43tmut7t/13/

Comment: @Evan well of course this code would not work if you change the OP's HTML structure. I don't know where you are going with this

Comment: I really want to you use your function but with no HTML structure. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes. Thank you. So simple. I'll play around with this now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the index of the anchor being clicked on, use jQuery's `.index()` function:

```
$('a').on("click", function () {
    alert('link' + $('ul li').index($(this).parent() ));
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/faoL8bxy/)**

Otherwise if you're after counting the number of times each link is clicked on, there's no need to use `.each()` or `count`:

```
$('a').data('link',0).on("click", function () {
    $(this).data('link', $(this).data('link') + 1);
    alert('link' + $(this).data('link'));
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/43tmut7t/9/)**

Use the custom data attribute to store the number of clicks on each link, setting it to zero on each on initially.

Comment: I think I made a mistake by include the <LI> in my structure. I'm talking about ALL links on a page absent of a type of structure. I just used LI for presentation purposes.

Comment: No. Not counting each time a link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In second case `$(this).each(...)` will be called just once - for the `this` element.

You should replace it by `$("a").each(...)` if you want all a's to be processed.

Comment: Yes, if that's your intention (it is not clear what you actually need).

Comment: However, this example is firing all links. It would only fire on each click. But the number would need to be in order. It seems to reset when I click on a different link.